# raspberry pi Bluetooth with react-native-bluetooth-classic getting Error:java.io.IOException:read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret:-1

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, raspberry-pi4

const handleDeviceConnect =  (item: BluetoothDevice) => {

```
item
    .connect()
    .then(device => {
        Alert.alert(`Connected to ${item.id}`);
        setDevcieConnected(item);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error::', err);
    });
```

};

Comment: Generally this error occurs when there isn't actually a `ServerSocket` waiting for the connection on the other side.  Have you checked the discussions on Github, a number of other people have commented on working with Raspberry Pis.

Comment: Yes there is problem in other side when $sudo rfcomm watch hc10 is run in raspberry pi terminal bluetooth is connected .